# Create data frame from Tocher's clustring method in r

Tags: r, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I used “biotools” package to calculate the Tocher’s clustering. The data have 17 varieties and they were divided into 6 clusters. The code and result is below.

```
data(garlicdist)   
   garlic <- tocher(garlicdist)   
   garlic


>  Tocher's Clustering 

$`cluster 1`
[1] 8  9  12 4  10 2  7  15

$`cluster 2`
[1] 1  6  14

$`cluster 3`
[1] 11 13

$`cluster 4`
[1] 3 5

$`cluster 5`
[1] 16

$`cluster 6`
[1] 17
```

Now I would like to create a matrix data from this Tocher's Clustering where varieties will be placed orderly and cluster name and cluster number will be placed according to the varieties like following data showed in a pic "variety distribution".[variety distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHVgh.png)

I would be grateful if anyone helps me to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please add the requested output directly to your question instead of linking a screenshot? The question will become better readable and you do not risk that the link to the screenshot might become invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a data.frame/tibble, not a matrix because you normally don't compute with the `cluster` character column (in the expected result). You cluster list is in `garlic$clusters`.

1. add NAs to each vector in the list so that each vector has the same length.
2. combine them into a matrix. Coerce the matrix to tibble
3. collapse them into pairs of names and values
4. add a column of cluster_no by extracting the digits in `cluster`
5. drop the NAs

The final code:

```
library(biotools)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

data(garlicdist)   
garlic <- tocher(garlicdist)
cluster_df <- garlic$clusters %>% 
  sapply("length<-", n = max(length(.))) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% gather(cluster, variety) %>% 
  mutate(cluster_no = str_extract(cluster, "[:digit:]+")) %>% 
  drop_na()
```

Comment: Wow...It is working. Thanks a lot for your response.